# Controle Spin Up/Down

Tags: php

Eu criei uma carrinho de compras e ví a necessidade de colocar um controle Spin Up/Down, porque preciso que o usuário edite o valor. Porém quando volto na galeria de produtos e solicito um outro produto e compro retornando para o carrinho de compras, tudo funciona direitinho, só que o valor editado não fixa. Qual seria a solução?

Comment: que é "controle Spin Up/Down"? De onde vem os valores?

Comment: É um tipo de <input  com o type="number". Fica uma seta pra cima e outra pra baixo. <td><input type="number" id="num_vit" placeholder="1" min="14" max="41">' . $numeracao . ' </td>.

Comment: Pois é amigo, ao fazer essa alteração no elemento vc precisa tb alterar onde essa informação é guardada. Por isso perguntei "de onde vem esses valores".

Comment: É um tipo de <input  com o type="number". Fica uma seta pra cima e outra pra baixo. <td><input type="number" id="num_vit" placeholder="1" min="14" max="41">' . $numeracao . ' </td>. Mas pode ser um input type= "text". Após enviar para o carrinho de compras, o cliente terá a opção de alterar a numeração. E assim que ele enviar novo produto para o carrinho, essa numeração precisa ser mantida. Mas até esse momento eu não gravei na base o pedido. Tem como gravar a variável na propria session carrinho e restaurá-la neste procedimento que o cliente fará?

Comment: Lógico, os dados do produto vem do banco de dados.

Comment: Vc precisa salvar isso em algum lugar. Senão não adianta alterar porque sempre que voltar pra página o valor vai ficar como está no HTML.

Comment: Eu só gravo o pedido após o cliente finalizar o mesmo, entrar com os dados de entrega e finalmente eu gerar um boleto de pagamento e enviar para o email.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78681/discussion-between-xavier-and-dvd).

Comment: Uma das formas é salvar no próprio navegador usando localStorage. Ou você poderia criar no banco um registro com as informações do carrinho e alterar via Ajax.